# Python matplotlib - ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache

Tags: python, pip, matplotlib

I have installed `matplotlib` for Python using `pip` which was completed without error. Yet I get this error when I try to import it:

```
import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import defaultParams, validate_backend, cycler
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 29, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/fontconfig_pattern.py", line 28, in <module>
    from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache
ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache
```

Comment: "functools_lru_cache.py" : Install  `python-backports.functools-lru-cache` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-backports.functools-lru-cache&searchon=names

Answer (score 5):

try this I had same problem this morning

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

I also am using python3.7
a little later after I installed a few modules. I ran.

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

I can now import matplotlib.

Answer (score 4):

Uninstall first

```
pip uninstall backports.functools_lru_cache
```

and then re-install it

```
pip install backports.functools_lru_cache
```

like described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47317710/4521646).